# Change Multiple Chart Series Labels

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have around 50 charts each on different sheets. Each chart shows a time series as series one and its trend as series 2 and they are labeled Series 1 and Series 2.

Is there any way I can change Series 1 to the Chart Sheet Name and Series 2 to "Trend" for all sheets?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
Sub UpdateCharts()
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each c In s.ChartObjects
            c.Activate
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = s.Name
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Trend"""
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @leal32b

Thanks for the help! I had to adjust the code a bit and this worked:

`Sub Change_Chart_Names()

    Dim C As Chart 

        For Each C In ActiveWorkbook.Charts 

        C.Activate

            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ActiveSheet.Name

            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Trend"""

        Next C

End Sub`

Comment: Ok, good! May you please mark my answer as "This answer is useful"? xD